# Call remote function from View - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, remote-server

I looking for a way to call `REMOTE FUNCTION` in `SELECT` clause in `VIEW`.
Basically I'am trying to do somthing like this:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_Year_Forcast] AS
        (SELECT    BshForecast.ProjectId, 
                   BshForecast.JobTypeId,
                   Job_Type.NAME,          
                   ProjectName , 
                   ProjectManagerID,                       
                   ProjectManagerName , 


***EXEC @START_DATE  =[192.168.0.10].[LudanProjectManager].[dbo].[func_Project_Get_Start_Date] @PROJECT_ID as [Start_Date],***

                   StartBudget , 
                   AdditionalBudget , 
                   TotalBudget  , 
                   UsedBudget ,   
        FROM       BshForecast  INNER  JOIN Job_Type ON BshForecast.JobTypeId = ID                   
        WHERE   (dbo.BshForecast.Year = DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()))   
                AND (dbo.BshForecast.IsDeleted = 0) 
                AND (dbo.BshForecast.BranchId = 200)
                AND (dbo.BshForecast.Approved = 1) );
```

And what I'am trying to get is a view that the seven'th column will hold the start date of each project that will be evaluate from a function in remote server.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of calling a remote function is `openquery`.  But `openquery` only takes a string literal, so you have to wrap the call to `openquery` in `exec`.

Here's an example that creates a function and calls it through the linked server called "localhost".

```
use TestDatabase
if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'fn_twice')
    drop function fn_twice
go
create function dbo.fn_twice(@i int) returns int as begin return 2*@i end
go
declare @i int
set @i = 21

declare @func_sql nvarchar(max)
set @func_sql = 'select @result = a.result from openquery(localhost, ' +
        '''select TestDatabase.dbo.fn_twice(' + 
        cast(@i as varchar(12)) + ') as result'') a'

declare @result int
exec sp_executesql @func_sql, N'@result int output', @result output

-- The result of the function call is now available in @result, and
-- you can use it in a query.
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't have to be `OPENQUERY`. You could call the function like this as well: `EXEC remoteserver.database..sp_executesql N'SELECT @result = dbo.FunctionName(arguments)', N'@result int output', @myresult output`. Maybe I'm missing something, though.

Comment: @AndriyM: If RPC and execute permissions on `sp_executesql` are allowed,  yours is a much cleaner solution

Comment: But yours are very good points, the one about RPC in particular. And I forgot that I actually meant to vote your suggestion up anyway, for I do remember once having to resort to using `OPENQUERY` just like that, when I needed to call a remote function.

Comment: But EXEC in view is not allowed , is there any ather solution?